Is there a way to fix the broken swiper slider?
In the previous few days, I had the swiper slider or sort working well, but then I'd try making more sliders for the page, and when things started to tangle, my landing page became a mess, and I don't know exactly what went wrong, I don't want to mess my page any further so I undo after try deleting all but one slider, and yet it still doesn't work.
This is my slider's original state; it changes image every few seconds
here is the slider state after a few days and after adding a few sliders
the codes are very similar to one another, but I place three of them in a separate part, the first one on the head and the rest on the body.
<html lang="en"></html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <title>AniMax. Watch and read your favorite Anime and Manga.</title>

<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: right;
        flex-wrap: flex;
        column-gap: 35px;
        font: 16px
        
      }
    </style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css">

    <!-- font awesome cdn link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">

    <!-- custom css file link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="AniMax-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.js">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- header section start -->
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo"><i class="fas fa-infinity"></i>AniMax.</a>
        <nav class="navbar">
             <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
             <a href="New-Release.html">New Release</a>
             <a href="manga.html">Manga/Novel</a>
             <a href="movies.html">Movies</a>
             <a href="episodes.html">Episodes</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-bars"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-search" id="search-icon"></i>
            <i href="#" class="fas fa-user"></i>
            <i href="#" class="fas fa-download"></i>
        </div>
    </header>



<!-- This is where slider 1 -->

<section class="home" id="home">

  <div class="swiper home-slider">

      <div class="swiper-wrapper">

          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box">
                      <div class="image">
                    <img class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/Oshi No Ko Season 2.jpg" 
                    alt="Oshi No Ko Season 2">
                    </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>OSHI NO KO</h3>
                      <p>SEASON 2 | AIR NOW</p>
                      <p> Sub|Dub</p>
                      <p>Continuation from previous season, Aqua, Akane and other actors<br>
                          preparing and navigate their acting to perform in stage play of <br>
                          adapted Manga "Tokyo Blade". Until Abiko the Author shows up and <br> 
                          revealing her dislike to adaptation demanding some changes.</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn">Watch Episode</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
          </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box">
                      <div class="image">
                    <img class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/Why Does Nobody Remember Me in This World.jpg" 
                    alt="Why Does Nobody Remember Me in This World">
                    </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>Why Does Nobody Remember Me <br>
                          in This World?</h3>
                      <p>SEASON 1 | AIR NOW</p>
                      <p> Sub|Dub</p>
                       <p>A young man named Kai belongs to the agency that protects humanity. While out with his childhood friend Jeanne,<br>
                          a world-changing event suddenly occurs. In a world without a hero, he inherits the sword and martial skills.....</p>
                          
                          <a href="#" class="btn">Watch Episode</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box ">
                  <div class="image">
                      <img class="image" class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/Failure Frame Season 1.jpg" 
                      alt="Failure Frame">
                   </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>Failure Frame</h3>
                      <p>SEASON 1 | AIR NOW</p>
                      <p> Sub|Dub</p>
                      <p>Touka Mimori and his classmates are suddenly summoned to a fantasy world by a goddess to act as heroes. While most of them are shown to have exceptional skills, Mimori has an E-rank. <br>
                         Deeming him to be useless, the goddess decides to banish Mimori to a dungeon where nobody has ever survived.</p>
                        

                          <a href="#" class="btn">Watch Episode</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img class="image" class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/Vanguard Divinez Season 2.jpg" 
                    alt="Failure Frame">
                 </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Cardfight!! Vanguard Divinez</h3>
                    <p>SEASON 2 | AIR NOW</p>
                    <p> Sub|Dub</p>
                    <p>Through his victory with Vanguard at the Fated Clash, Akina Myodo has his wish for the health of his sister Hikari Myodo fulfilled. Gabwelius, who assembled the owners of the Fated One cards, <br>
                       reveals the truth behind the Fated Clash.</p>
                      

                        <a href="#" class="btn">Watch Episode</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box ">
                  <div class="image">
                      <img class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/Days with My Stepsister.jpg" 
                      alt="Days with My Stepsister">
                  </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>Days with My Stepsister</h3>
                      <p>SEASON 1 | AIR NOW</p>
                      <p> Sub|Dub</p>
                      <p>Yuuta Asamura gets a new stepsister after his father remarries, Saki Ayase, who happens to be the number one beauty of the school <br>
                          year. They promise each other not to be too close, not to be too opposing, and to simply keep a vague and comfortable distance, Saki, who has worked alone for the sake of her family,<br>
                           doesn't know how to properly rely on others, whereas Yuuta is unsure of how to truly treat her....</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn">Watch Episode</a>
                          <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>

  </div>

</section>





<!-- This is where slider 2 -->

<h1 class="heading">High Anticipation series in 2025</h1>

<section class="home" id="home">

  <div class="swiper home-slider">

      <div class="swiper-wrapper">

          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box">

                      <div class="image">
                    <img class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/The 100 Girlfriend Who Really Love You Season 2.jpg"
                    alt="The 100 Girlfriend Who Really Love You Season 2">
                    </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>The 100 Girlfriend Who Really Love You Season 2</h3>
                      <p> Coming January, 2025</p>
                      <p>Rentarō Aijō has confessed to (and been rejected by) 100 girls in his lifetime. On the last day of middle school, he visits a shrine and prays that he get a girlfriend during his time at high school. </br>
                        Suddenly, the God of Love appears and tells Rentarō that the reason for his non-existent love life is because everyone is only supposed to have one soulmate in their life. Due to an error on </br>
                        the God of Love's part, Rentarō is destined to have 100 which is to begin when he enters high school. </p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn">Remind Me Later</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
          </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box">
                      <div class="image">
                    <img class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/I've Been Killing Slimes for 300 Years Season 2.jpg" 
                    alt="I've Been Killing Slimes for 300 Years Season 2">
                    </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>I've Been Killing Slimes for 300 Years Season 2</h3>
                      <p> Coming January, 2025</p>
                       <p>After living a painful life as an office worker on Earth, Azusa ends up dying from overworking. She finds herself reincarnated as an undying, unaging witch in a new world, and now she vows to spend her days as pleasantly and stress-free as possible. She makes a living by hunting slimes, the easiest targets. 
                        But after centuries of doing this simple job, she has become extremely powerful and finds that she can no longer maintain her low-key lifestyle. </p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn">Remind Me Later</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <div class="box ">
                  <div class="image">
                      <img class="image" class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/My Happy Marriage Season 2.jpg" 
                      alt="My Happy Marriage Season 2">
                   </div>
                  <div class="content">
                      <h3>My Happy Marriage Season 2</h3>
                      <p> TBA, 2025</p>
                      <p>In an alternative version of the Taishō era in which spirits and magic are real, but in decline, Miyo Saimori, born without supernatural talent,is forced into an existence of servitude by her abusive stepmother. When Miyo finally comes of marriageable age, though, her hopes of being whisked away to a better life crumble after she discovers her fiancé’s identity: Kiyoka Kudou, a commander apparently so cold and cruel that his previous would-be brides all fled within three days of their engagements. With no home to return to, Miyo resigns herself to her fate—and soon finds that her pale and handsome </br>
                        husband-to-be is anything but the monster she expected. </p>
                     
                         <a href="#" class="btn">Remind Me Later</a>
                         <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="box ">
                <div class="image">
                    <img class="image" class="image" src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/ANIMAX/Image Source/Classroom of The Elite Season 4.jpg" 
                    alt="Classroom of The Elite Season 4">
                 </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Classroom of The Elite Season 4</h3>
                    <p> TBA, 2025</p>
                    <p>The Japanese government has established the Tokyo Metropolitan Advanced Nurturing School, dedicated to instruct and foster the generation of people that will support the country in the future. The students are given a high degree of freedom in order to closely mimic real life. 
                      The story follows the perspective of Kiyotaka Ayanokōji, a quiet and modest boy, who is bad at making friends and would rather keep his distance, but possesses unrivaled intelligence and incredible physical ability. He is a student of Class-D, which is where the school dumps its inferior students, widely considered "defective". </p>
                   
                       <a href="#" class="btn">Remind Me Later</a>
                       <a href="#" class="btn">Read Manga</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          

      </div>

  </div>

</section>

What I did is separate all slider to different new files since it was the problem, and then reedit css file adjusted all but it went further from being fix, I look around on internet it say it was because of browser cookies, or the damage extension, etc. Should I remade everything on the slider from scratch or stop using slider too many?
